# How to dynamically update properties files without restarting a topology?

Tags: java, properties, apache-storm

I need to design a topology in apache storm which reads multiple properties files. In my original design, the properties will be loaded when topology created, and each bolt will get needed properties by using parameters, such as `builder.setBolt("Bolt1", new Bolt1(param1, param2, ...), 3)...`. However, each time when I want to update properties files, I have to restart the topology and this action will clean in-memory data. I don't want to get this result, however, loading properties files in each bolt is costly and it is not a good design.

I have another thought. I use a bolt to load properties files and save them in a `parameter object`. This bolt is after a spout and it will emit the `parameter object` to next bolt. In this design `parameter object` will be emitted to bolts needed it, and it can prevent to access properties files too many times.

However, I am not sure whether it is a good design, or there exists a better one. Please give me some suggestions. Many thanks!

Comment: You can have one extra spout which will be polling for changes in your properties files which is stored somewhere and on detecting any changes it will emit that file as tuple to all the bolts. On receveing tuple from that spout all the bolts can update their properties.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store the configuration files in HDFS and periodically reload them inside your bolts using [tick tuples](http://kitmenke.com/blog/2014/08/04/tick-tuples-within-storm/) (disclaimer: my blog post about using tick tuples).

For example:

```
@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
   try {
      if (isTickTuple(tuple)) {
          // refresh our configs from HDFS
          _fileLoader.load(_configs);
         return;
      }

     // do your bolt stuff 
     // use configs you loaded earlier
     // ...
   } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error("Bolt execute error: {}", e);
      collector.reportError(e);
   }
}
```

I chose HDFS because the API is simple and works well with [parsing libraries like jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). For example:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(_hdfsUrl), new Configuration());
String path = "hdfs://server/folder/something.json";
Path p = new Path(path);
if (fs.exists(p)) {
   InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(fs.open(p))
   Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   map = mapper.readValue(istream, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>>() {});
}
```

In response to "loading properties files in each bolt is costly and it is not a good design"... I disagree. Your bolts are going to be distributed across the cluster to many different nodes in many different workers (aka many different JVMs). This means you will need to load the config inside multiple instances of the same bolt. Plus, if you want to dynamically reload the config you're going to need that mechanism inside your bolt somewhere.

Another option would be to use Zookeeper but honestly the API is a pain to use and HDFS has worked perfectly.